# How do I output a numeric value in Assmbler (GAS)

Tags: assembly, output, gnu-assembler

I'm quite new to ASM so please excuse me if the question is too silly. I'm using GAS + Ubuntu 12.04.

I have done the following:

```
.data
    x:  .ascii "15"

.text

.global _start

_start:
    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $x, %ecx
    movl $2, %edx
    int $0x80

EndProg:
    movl $1, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

The above **works fine** and outputs 15. But when I try to **output it as a long**, it shows nothing. And no errors either.

Here's my non-working code:

```
.data
    x:  .long 15

.text

.global _start

_start:
    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $x, %ecx
    movl $4, %edx # I'm assuming 4 bytes for long.
    int $0x80

EndProg:
    movl $1, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to print a number, you need to compose it to individual characters which make up the number. You can decide whether you want it in decimal, hexadecimal or any other format.

Alternatively, call `printf` to do it for you.

Comment: Reluctant (due to code size), but I decided to use printf.